# Update dataGrid using Ajax in PrimeFaces

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, primefaces, datagrid

I want to update the table without reloading the page using primefaces ajax, but I can't do it, page is reloaded.
Here I realize ajax:

```
<p:commandButton value="#{letter}" action="searchByLetter" styleClass="noborder-button" actionListener="#{searchCriteria.setLetter(letter)}" >
   <p:ajax process="@form" update=":booksForm:booksList"/>
</p:commandButton>
```

Here I only want to restart the table

```
<h:form id="booksForm" >
    <p:dataGrid rowIndexVar="rowIndex" columns="2" lazy="true" var="b" 
                value="${libraryFacade.books}"  id="booksList" styleClass="books_list"  paginator="true" rows="2" 
                paginatorPosition="bottom" rowsPerPageTemplate="2,4,6" 
                paginatorTemplate="{RowsPerPageDropdown} {PageLinks}"  
                paginatorAlwaysVisible="true" emptyMessage="">
```

Comment: Please provide a *MCVE* http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Sorry ) Minimize and corrected the issue )

Comment: why are you using `action`? just use the `actionListener`.

Comment: @stg:  you can type [ mcve ] (without the whitespace in it. And it resolves it for you like [mcve]

Comment: This is not an mcve. There is e.g. no bean posted...

Comment: Nobody knows what is the problem?

Comment: @Apostolos: please carefully read http://stackoverflow.com/q/3909267 before continuing to spread misinformation.